# Array and string, exchange

Tags: php, arrays, string

My code:

```
<?php

    $string = "hello world";
    echo $string[1];          //output is 'e'
    echo end($string);        // I've got a warning error

  ?>
```

How can I exchange my string variable to an array format?
I think if I exchange it the problem will solve.

Comment: What is the problem you want to solve?

Comment: As you know, If you have an array like this $a = array(1,2,3,45,6,7);
with this pre-defined function end(); you can reach and get the lastest element of an array.
So I found out a string can be as array in PHP, but here is Not working like an array.

Comment: Ok, but that still does not explain what you are trying to do. Why do you want to call `end` on a string?

Comment: Wouldn't calling `end` really return a null if it worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a predefined function that do this. It's str_split(). Here http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php you find the doc

Comment: @wandad that should be what you really needed.

Answer (score 4):

`$string[n]` is a specific notation to access the nth offset of a string. This does not mean the string is an array, it's just special syntactic sugar. If you want the last offset of the string, use `substr($string, -1)`.

Comment: I knew, I can access to the last offset of a string, But I wanna know can I exchange  a string to an array?

Comment: You can explode the string into an array. But that's rather wasteful and nonsensical if you can do the same thing while keeping the string as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
echo substr($string, -1);
```

Because a string is not natively an array, functions like `end` and `array_sort` don't work.

To physically cast the string, use this:

```
function CastStringToArray($string)
{
    $ret = array();
    $length = strlen($string);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
    {
        $ret[] = $string[$i];
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: This does not work, not the least because an array cast to a string will result in an array with the whole string at index 0.

Comment: Thanks but I do not want these anwsers.

Comment: There is nothing else, but this. If you want to physically cast the string to an array, that's something else. I added a function that can do that. But I would stick to using `substr` instead as loops and adding to arrays can kill performance.

Comment: Plus function calls are a huge perf killer in PHP.